# Односвязный список, удаление элемента, C++

Tags: c++, указатели, список

Добрый день. Есть вот такой код удаления элемента из списка

```
void del(int n) // n - позиция удаляемого элемента
{
    // Mass - объекты, которые хранятся в списке
    Mass *temp = HEAD, *helping = temp;

    if ((temp != NULL) && (n <= size) && (n >= 0)) // если по этому номеру что-то лежит и этот элемент внутри списка
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            helping = temp; // предыдущее значение temp
            temp = temp->Next;
        }

        if (temp == HEAD) // если элемент который надо удалить первый
        {
            helping = temp;
            temp = temp->Next;
            HEAD = temp;
            cout << "Удаляемый элемент: " << *helping;
            free(helping);
            size--; // уменьшаем размер списка
            return;
        }
        else // иначе, если он в середине или конце
        {
            // 0 1 2 3 4
            // вводится, к примеру, 2. т.е. helping = 1, temp = 2;
            free(temp);
            size--;
            // 0 1 .. 3 4
            helping->Next = helping->Next->Next;
            // т.е. теперь 1 указывает не на 2, а на 3.
        }
    }
```

Начало отрабатывается хорошо, т.е. первый элемент он удаляет, а вот другие элементы почему-то не получается. Думаю над этим уже второй день, голова кипит. 
Представляю себе алгоритм так:

1. Удаляем элемент
2. Смещаем остальные элементы списка (слева к удаляемому или справа?)

или вообще сделать так
1. Удаляем элемент

2. Проходим весь список пока не наткнемся на удаленный (NULL)
3. Перебрасываем ссылку с элемента перед удаленным на элемент после удаленного (минуя сам удаленный элемент)
4. Повторяем п.3 пока не будет нулевых элементов. Учитывая, что конец списка мы не рассматриваем.

---

Всем огромное спасибо за помощь! Открыл много нового для себя в работе с указателями. Отдельное спасибо

@MichaelPak за указание направления в которую стоит копать и указания конкретной ошибки и подробного объяснения,

@Mike за то, что поругал за использование нерационального алгоритма

@alexolut за то, что подсказал разницу в между `ned delete` и `malloc free`

@Vlad from Moscow за подробное решение задачи и классную идею о использовании переменной беззнакового типа (так и сделал в итоге).

Я вам очень благодарен, спасибо большое!

Comment: если *другие элементы почему-то не получается* может покажите код *else // иначе, если он в середине или конце*

Comment: @Saidolim конечно. Добавил в код, но не уверен в правильности рассуждений

Comment: Если уж код действительно на C++, то лучше использовать `new/delete`, а не `malloc/free`.

Comment: @alexolut большое спасибо! Просто увидел использование free в примере и подцепил к своему коду. Буду знать, что это сишная вещь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе у вас написано все правильно за исключением двух моментов.

Первое - это номер удаляемого элемента не может быть равен `size` . `size` всегда на единицу больше, чем номер последнего существующего элемента, так как нумерация элементов у вас начинается с 0.

Поэтому вместо условия

```
    if ((temp != NULL) && (n <= size) && (n >= 0)) // если по этому номеру что-то лежит и этот элемент внутри списка
```

вам следует написать

```
    if ((temp != NULL) && (n < size) && (n >= 0)) // если по этому номеру что-то лежит и этот элемент внутри списка
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Вы бы облегчили себе жизнь, если бы переменная `size` имела беззнаковый целый тип. В этом случае не было бы необходимости проверять, что `n >= 0`. Вы могли бы `size` объявить, как имеющую тип `unsigned int` или, как обычно принято, `size_t`.

Второе - это вы пытаетесь обратиться к уже удаленному элементу в предложении

```
helping->Next = helping->Next->Next;
```

Следовало сначала установить значение поля `Next`, а лишь затем удалять элемент.

С учетом сказанного функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void del(int n) // n - позиция удаляемого элемента
{
    if ((HEAD != NULL) && (n < size) && (n >= 0)) // если по этому номеру что-то лежит и этот элемент внутри списка
    {
        // Mass - объекты, которые хранятся в списке
        Mass *temp = HEAD, *helping = HEAD;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            helping = temp; // предыдущее значение temp
            temp = temp->Next;
        }

        if (temp == HEAD) // если элемент который надо удалить первый
        {
            HEAD = temp->Next;
        }
        else
        {
            helping->Next = temp->Next;
        }
        cout << "Удаляемый элемент: " << *temp;
        free(temp);
        size--; // уменьшаем размер списка
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Списки хуже массивов тем, что в списках нельзя обратиться к элементу сразу: для этого необходимо пройтись через предыдущие элементы. Поэтому процесс удаления выглядит следующим образом:

1. Доходишь до элемента, ссылка `NEXT` которого указывает на удаляемый элемент;
2. Присваиваешь ссылку `NEXT` удаляемого элемента ссылке предыдущего элемента;
3. Удаляешь элемент;
4. Profit!

Таким образом из такого картины:

```
           +------+    +------+    +------+  
           |данные|    |данные|    |данные|
    \/\/\->+------+    +------+    +------+
           |      |--->|      |--->|  0   |
           +------+    +------+    +------+
```

получается такая:

```
           +------+    +------+    +------+
           |данные|    |удален|    |данные|
    \/\/\->+------+    +------+    +------+
           |      |    |  0   | .->|  0   |
           +------+    +------+ |  +------+
                 \______________|
```

У тебя же проблема заключается в том, что ты сначала удаляешь элемент, а потом пытаешься найти ссылку на следующий, то есть `helping->Next->Next` после удаления  уже не указывает на 3-ий элемент. Попробуй сначала провести работу с указателями, а уже потом удалить элемент.

Comment: Отличные иллюстрации )

Answer (score 5):

2 Раза бегать по цепочке - это перебор. Лучше, двигаясь по цепочке, запоминать предыдущий элемент.

```
Mass *temp=HEAD,*prev=NULL;
int i=0;
while(temp && i<n)
 {
  i++;
  prev=temp; // Запоминаем предыдущий в цепочке
  temp=temp->next;
 }
if(!temp) // Элемент не найден
 {
  return;
 }
if(HEAD==temp)
 {
  HEAD=temp->next;
 } else
 {
  if(prev) prev->next=temp->next;
 }
cout << "Удаляемый элемент: " << *temp;
size--;
free(temp);
```